# What's a good Data Model in Mongo for my data?

Tags: mongodb, data-modeling

I am looking to store following data:

- TV Shows
- Seasons within a TV show
- Episodes within a season
- Talents within a episode

I currently have it it MySQL stored across 4 tables (shows, seasons, episodes, talents). I am looking to find a proper Data Model in MongoDB.

I am considering nesting the data like this:
Show->Seasons->Episodes->Talents

Will nesting the data like that make it hard to update certain fields?

I am new to this so I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deeply nested structures can make it difficult to work with a MongoDB collection. However, if you'd like to build a nested structure you could do something like this:

```
  [{'show':{'name':'ShowName', 
             'seasons':[{'name':'SeasonOne',
                         'episodes':
                                    [{'name':'EpisodeOne',
                                      'talents':['talentOne',
                                                 'talentTwo',
                                                 'talentN']
                                    }]
                        },
                        {'name':'SeasonTwo',
                         'episodes':
                                    [{'name':'EpisodeOne',
                                      'talents':['talentOne',
                                                 'talentTwo',
                                                 'talentN']
                                    }]
                        }]
           }},
      {'show':{'name':'ShowNameTwo', 
             'seasons':[{'name':'SeasonOne',
                         'episodes':
                                    [{'name':'EpisodeOne',
                                      'talents':['talentOne',
                                                 'talentTwo',
                                                 'talentN']
                                    }]
                        },
                        {'name':'SeasonTwo',
                         'episodes':
                                    [{'name':'EpisodeOne',
                                      'talents':['talentOne',
                                                 'talentTwo',
                                                 'talentN']
                                    }]
                        }]
           }}]
```

Then you could query a specific show by its name:

```
db.show.find({"show.name":"ShowName"})
```

Or even get all shows that star a certain talent:

```
db.show.find({"show.seasons.episodes.talents":"talentOne"})
```